# Resumable & multipart file upload to google drive using Http. last chunk overflow error

Tags: java, google-drive-api, multipartform-data, httpurlconnection

So I am using the guidelines for resumable/multipart upload of files to google drive as per the specifications of the google docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

Everything goes great I have written this code a long time ago and it had worked for so many files for a long time until just yesterday i tried using the same code to upload an sample file which is not an multiple of 256KB[again specified from google docs]

Here are the related classes

1) URLMaker :- HttpUrlFactory for constant chunk uploads

```
 /*A Utility Class for constantly creating URL connections for each chunk upload as an instance can be used to send only one request */
 final class URLMaker 
 {
     static HttpURLConnection openConnection(String session, String method, String[] params, String[] values, boolean input, boolean output)throws IOException
     {
      HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(session).openConnection();

      request.setRequestMethod(method);
      request.setDoInput(input);
      request.setDoOutput(output);
      request.setConnectTimeout(10000);

     //params & values array are of equal length so just one->one key:value pass it as headers
      for(int i=0;i<params.length;i++){request.setRequestProperty(params[i],values[i]);}

      return request;
   }
 }
```

2) Session :- Used To Retrive an resumable uri session which i save to an file and read from later on

```
final class Session
{
 private static final File SESSION=new File("E:/Session.txt");

 private static String read()
 {
  try(ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(SESSION)))
  {
   URISession session=(URISession)ois.readObject();

   return session.uri;
  }
  catch(Exception ex){return null;}
 }

 static String makeSession(String token,File file)throws Exception
 {
  if(SESSION.exists()){return read();} //If I Previously saved an resumable URI reload that from file

  String body = "{\"name\": \"" + file.getName() + "\"}";

  String fields[]=new String[5];
  fields[0]="Authorization";
  fields[1]="X-Upload-Content-Type";
  fields[2]="X-Upload-Content-Length";
  fields[3]="Content-Type";
  fields[4]="Content-Length";

  String values[]=new String[5];
  values[0]="Bearer "+token;
  values[1]="*audio/mp3*";           //generic octet stream
  values[2]=String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d",file.length());
  values[3]="application/json; charset=UTF-8";
  values[4]=String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", body.getBytes().length);

  HttpURLConnection request =URLMaker.openConnection("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable"
                                                    ,"POST"
                                                    ,fields,values, true, true);
  try(OutputStream outputStream = request.getOutputStream()){outputStream.write(body.getBytes());}

  request.connect();

  if(request.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
  {
   String uri=request.getHeaderField("location");

   SESSION.createNewFile();

   write(uri);

   return uri;
  }
  else
  {
   System.err.println(request.getResponseCode()+"/"+request.getResponseMessage());

   System.out.println(new String(request.getErrorStream().readAllBytes()));
  }
  return null;
 }

 private static void write(String uri)
 {
  try(ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(SESSION)))
  {
   oos.writeObject(new URISession(uri));
  }
  catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace(System.out);}
 }

 private static class URISession implements Serializable
 {
  private final String uri;

  private URISession(String uri){this.uri=uri;}
 }
}
```

the class where my problem lies

3)Uploader :- Uploads the data from file to uri

```
final class Uploader 
{
 private static final int
 KB=1024,
 _256KB=256*KB; 

 public static void uploadFile(String session,File file)throws IOException
 {
  long uploadPosition,bytesDone,workLeft;
  if((uploadPosition=getLastUploadedByte(session,file.length()))==-1){return;} //read the last uploaded byte position[0-length-1 value] if this upload previously failed due to network/server issues
  bytesDone=uploadPosition;  //if +ve value it means my work is a little less

  String
  fields[]={"Content-Type","Content-Length","Content-Range"},
  values[]=new String[]{"audio/mp3*","",""}; 

  try(RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r"))
  {
   raFile.seek(uploadPosition); 

   byte buffer[]=new byte[_256KB];
   while((workLeft=raFile.read(buffer))!=-1)  //read certain amount of work/or bytes to be uploaded
   {
    int code=0;
    while(workLeft>0)// it is possible that google might not have uploaded all my bytes I have sent so I keep trying until what I have read has been completely uploaded
    {
     values[1]=String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d",workLeft);
     values[2]="bytes "+uploadPosition+"-"+(uploadPosition + workLeft - 1)+"/"+file.length();

     System.out.println("Specified Range="+values[1]+"/"+values[2]);

     HttpURLConnection request=URLMaker.openConnection(session,"PUT",fields,values, true, true);
     try(OutputStream bytes=request.getOutputStream()){bytes.write(buffer,0,(int)workLeft);}  
     request.connect();

     code=request.getResponseCode();
     if(code==308)   //Means successful but more data needs to be uploaded
     {
      String range = request.getHeaderField("range");
      int bytesSent=Integer.parseInt(range.substring(range.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, range.length())) + 1
     System.out.println("Sent Range="+range);

      workLeft-=bytesSent;  //Work Reduced By this many bytes
      bytesDone+=bytesSent; //Progress increased by this many bytes

      System.out.println("Bytes="+bytesDone+"/"+file.length());
     }
     else if(code!=200)
     {
      System.err.println("Upload Error:"+request.getResponseMessage());
      System.err.println("Upload Error Msg:"+new String(request.getErrorStream().readAllBytes()));

      code=-1;
      break;
     }

     request.disconnect();
    }

    if(code==-1){return;}
    else if(code==200 || code==201){System.out.println("Upload Completed");}
   } 
  }
 }

 private static long getLastUploadedByte(String session,long fileLength)throws IOException
 {
  HttpURLConnection request = URLMaker.openConnection(session
                                                     ,"PUT"
                                                     ,new String[]{"Content-Length","Content-Range"}
                                                     ,new String[]{"0","bytes */" + fileLength},true,true);

  try(OutputStream output=request.getOutputStream()){output.flush();}

  request.connect();

  long chunkPosition=-1;
  if(request.getResponseCode()==308 || request.getResponseCode()==200)
  {
   String range = request.getHeaderField("range"); //previously sent byte position[ it's a 0-length-1 value]
   if(range==null){return 0;} //suppose it's my first time ever using this uri then there would have been no bytes uploaded and hence no range header
   chunkPosition = Long.parseLong(range.substring(range.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, range.length())) + 1;//format[0-value]
  }
  else
  {
   System.err.println("Seek Error:"+request.getResponseCode()+"/"+request.getResponseMessage());
   System.err.println("Seek Error Msg:"+new String(request.getErrorStream().readAllBytes()));
  }

  request.disconnect();

  return chunkPosition;
 }
}
```

And My Main Class

```
class FileUpload 
{
 private static final Credential getCredentials(NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT,String authorize,Collection<String> SCOPES,boolean clearTokens)throws IOException,GeneralSecurityException
 {
  // Load client secrets.    
  InputStream in = GDrive.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
  if (in == null){throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);}
  GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

  // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
  GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY,clientSecrets,SCOPES)
          .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new File("tokens")))
          .setAccessType("offline")
          .build();

  LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
  return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,receiver).authorize(authorize);
 }

 public static Credential makeCredentials(String authorize,Collection<String> SCOPES,boolean clearTokens)throws IOException,GeneralSecurityException
 {
  NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

  return getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT,authorize,SCOPES,clearTokens);
 }

 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
 {
  Credential credentials=makeCredentials("user",List.of(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));//authorize,scopes

  File media=new File("E:\\Music\\sample.mp3");

  String session=Session.makeSession(credentials.getAccessToken(),media);

  System.out.println("Session="+session);
  if(session==null){return;}

  Uploader.uploadFile(session,media);
 }
}
```

Now here is the problem i have an 2.01 MB (21,13,939 bytes) you can even download the file  and test it yourself from [here](https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3) or use any similar file

This is the log file

```
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939 Ok so I start of good uploading the first 256KB of data at every step
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=262144/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=524288/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939   //No Problems here still an multiple of 256KB
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=786432/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=1048576/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=1310720/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=1572864/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=1835008/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=2097152/2113939

//       HERE IS WHERE LOGIC IS THROWN OUT THE WINDOW  THE LAST CHUNK   //

Specified Range=16787/bytes 0-16786/2113939  <---- I am clearly telling google that this is the last 16786 bytes of data of my file 
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143         <---- But google dosen't seem to care and uploads the whole 256KB byte array along with the garbage data from the previous read
Bytes=2359296/2113939     <--- And now I have uploaded more bytes than the actual file itself [format is bytesDone/fileSize]
```

and the last response code i get before the app exits with no error is `308` I expect to see the message `"Upload Completed"` but it never does and the **File never shows up on my google drive.**

As You can already guess this code worked for files <256KB or multiples of it thats why i have never seen any problems with this code until now

I posted all the classes so that anyone can just copy and test it for themself but the main problem **i suspect lies in the Uploader class a**nd that's where i need your help.

Comment: This seems like a small file, is there any reason why you can't directly do this in one big request? What is the error message being thrown here? Maybe you have put in your question too unnecessary code. Also, is there any reason to not use the google Libraries?

Comment: I don't use the standard v2/v3 library because there is no command to terminate/pause the upload session but with this approach I can just use an Boolean or an Thread.interupted() in the while loop for termination and the getLastByteUploaded() ensures I resume where I left off if I do terminate it

Comment: Yes true I can upload it  with one request but the docs says that resumable/multipart approach can be used for both small/large files with the overhead of just one extra request at the end. As for error message the problem is there is none!!! my program uploads excess bytes than specified for the last chunk and the session doesn't terminate with 200 but rather with 308(Still Pending) so the file never shows up on my drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found your problem, from a piece of your output:

```
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939 Ok so I start of good uploading the first 256KB of data at every step
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=262144/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=524288/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939   //No Problems here still an multiple of 256KB
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
Bytes=786432/2113939
Specified Range=262144/bytes 0-262143/2113939
```

Looking at your code the part that actually goes inside `Content-Range` is the third position of the `values` array:

```cs
values[2]="bytes "+uploadPosition+"-"+(uploadPosition + workLeft - 1)+"/"+file.length();
```

It seems that you are not updating the variable `uploadPoistion` so you are always sending the same range over and over. You can see that even from the response you get from drive:

```cs
String range = request.getHeaderField("range"); // This is always the same
int bytesSent=Integer.parseInt(range.substring(range.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, range.length())) + 1
System.out.println("Sent Range="+range);
```

```
Sent Range=bytes=0-262143
```

This value repeats in your log over and over, so you are just informing the first 262144 bytes of information.

You should try to increase the `Content-Range` every time to cover all the bytes of the file:

```
bytes 0-262143/2113939
bytes 262144-524287/2113939
bytes 524288- ....
```

Comment: I see I will try it out and let you know

Comment: Yes that worked for me. I have posted an updated answer extending from your's for completeness sake

Answer (score 1):

This is an follow up on `@Raserhin` answer which worked for me . I am just posting the full code here.

CHANGES

1)renamed uploadPosition to driveIndex

2) Sent Range doesn't return the bytes uploaded per chunk but returns the EOF pointer for the file with each chunk upload[0- last index position of the file uploaded]

3) `driveIndex` should be assigned with the Range returned

4) an `localPosition` should be introduced in the while loop so as to read bytes from where the previous uploaded succeded

CODE

```
public static void uploadFile(String session,File file)throws IOException
 {
  long driveIndex;
  if((driveIndex=getLastUploadedByte(session,file.length()))==-1){return;}

  String
  fields[]={"Content-Type","Content-Length","Content-Range"},
  values[]=new String[]{"audio/mp3","",""}; 

  long fileIndex;
  int localPos,workLeft;
  int bytesLeft,bytesUploaded;

  try(RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r"))
  {
   raFile.seek(driveIndex); 

   byte buffer[]=new byte[_256KB];
   while((workLeft=raFile.read(buffer))!=-1)
   {
    int code=0;
    localPos=0;
    fileIndex=raFile.getFilePointer();

    while(workLeft>0)
    {
     values[1]=String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d",0);
     values[2]="bytes "+driveIndex+"-"+(driveIndex + workLeft - 1)+"/"+file.length();

     HttpURLConnection request=URLMaker.openConnection(session,"PUT",fields,values, true, true);
     try(OutputStream bytes=request.getOutputStream()){bytes.write(buffer,localPos,workLeft);}
     request.connect();

     code=request.getResponseCode();
     if(code==308)
     {
      String range = request.getHeaderField("range");
      driveIndex=Long.parseLong(range.substring(range.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, range.length())) + 1;

      bytesLeft=(int)(fileIndex-driveIndex);
      bytesUploaded=workLeft-bytesLeft;

      workLeft-=bytesUploaded;           //bytes left to uploaded decreases
      localPos+=(int)bytesUploaded;      //next read start's from the next chunk 

      System.out.println(driveIndex+"/"+(file.length()-1));
     }
     else if(code==200)
     {
      System.out.println("Upload Completed");
      break;
     }
     else
     {
      System.err.println("Upload Error:"+request.getResponseMessage());
      System.err.println("Upload Error Msg:"+new String(request.getErrorStream().readAllBytes()));

      code=-1;
      break;
     }

     request.disconnect();
    } 
    if(code==-1 || code==200){break;}
   } 
   System.out.println("File Closed");
  }
  System.out.println("End");
 }
```

For anyone wanting explanation of the logic here is an rough sample

```
Current=last uploaded byte index to drive [Assume finished at index 2]
FilePos=is the Filepointer after reading from Current[Here for example purpose we assume we read 5 bytes]


   [2]       [7]
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 <--------- File=10
    ^         ^
    |         |
 Current    FilePos

Bytes read                                              = 2,3,4,5,6,7
Local pos                                               = 0

while(workLeft>0)
{
 Cycle 1
 Bytes read                                              = 2,3,4,5,6,7[6 Bytes,Last Index=7]
 Work left                                               = 6
 Bytes uploaded                                          = 2,3[Assume only 2 bytes were uploaded for explanation sake,Last Index=3]                                     


 Num of bytes left[FilePos-UploadPos]                    = 7-3=>4
 Number of bytes uploaded[Work Left-Num of bytes left]   = 6-4=>2

 Work left-=Number of bytes uploaded                     = 6-2=>4
 Local pos+=Number of bytes uploaded                     = 0+2=>2

 Cycle 2
 Bytes Read                                              = 2,3,4,5,6,7[Last Index=7]
 Work left                                               = 4
 Bytes uploaded                                          = -,-,4,5,6[Assume Only 3 bytes were uploaded,Last Index=6]

 Num of bytes left[FilePos-UploadPos]                    = 7-6=>1
 Number of bytes uploaded[Work Left-Num of bytes left]   = 4-1=>3

 Work left-=Number of bytes uploaded                     = 4-3=>1
 Local Pos+=Number of bytes uploaded                     = 2+3=>5

 Cycle 3
 Bytes Read                                              = 2,3,4,5,6,7[Last Index=7]
 Work left                                               = 1
 Bytes uploaded                                          = -,-,-,-,-,7[Last Byte Uploaded,Last Index=7]

 Num of bytes left[FilePos-UploadPos]                    = 7-7=>0
 Number of bytes uploaded[Work Left-Num of bytes left]   = 1-0=>1

 Work left-=Number of bytes uploaded                     = 1-2=>0
 Local Pos+=Number of bytes uploaded                     = 5+1=>6
}
//when workleft becomes 0 while loop break's
```